# "limited" access to wifi after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, windows-8.1

After my sister upgraded her Lenovo laptop to Windows 8.1, her internet connection keeps showing "limited" connection. She can't access to internet. However, my Toshiba laptop (Windows 7) can access to internet. Even though we tried to restart her laptop and even disconnect and reconnect the modem few times, same problem still occur. Please help.

Comment: You will have to un-install and re-install the wireless card driver. In order to do this you will need to get the exact model of the Lenovo laptop and the model of the wireless card. Please update your question with both of these details if possible.

Comment: @Ivy - Have you tried to "forget" the network then try connecting again.  Have you installed all required drivers for the network device.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: i don't know what is wireless card actually. but her model is Lenovo G480.

Comment: @Ramhound: tried. still cannot. what else to install? (fyi, i'm female who don't know how to backup files. :p )

Comment: @Ivy - Install Windows 8.1 compatible drivers for the network card.

Comment: @Ramhound: sorry... still don't know what is that... how can i install that? is there a link to download?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go to Lenovo's website and find the Lenovo G480 and download the Atheros Wireless driver:

Website for drivers:

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT073631

In the Category dropdown box choose `Networking Wireless LAN`

I think you need the first choice that comes up:

`Atheros WLan Driver for Windows 8.1(32-bit, 64-bit) - IdeaPad G480(2184, 20149)G580(2189, 20150)G780`

Before installing this you will have to uninstall the previous driver from your `Add/Remove programs` window. I highly recommend getting someone knowledgeable to help you with this.

Comment: Appreciate very much. will ask my brother and see how.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

Open a CMD prompt as an Administrator.  It must be run as administrator.   To do so as an administrator, right click on "CMD" in the Metro interface, and choose the run as administrator option at the bottom of the screen.

Type this: netsh winsock reset

Press enter.

Reboot your computer.